# My commit-msg hook - when using full editor, comments are added to commit message

Tags: git

I want to prepend my commit messages automatically with my Branch name, in square brackets, such as:

> [Branch Name] Made a change

Here is my commit-msg hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Automatically adds branch name and branch description to every commit message.
#
BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | awk -F'/' '{print $3}')

if [ -n "$BRANCH" ]; then
        echo ["$BRANCH"'] '$(cat "$1") > "$1"
fi
```

This hook works fine if I use **git commit -am "Commit message"**.  But if I use simply **git commit** to use the full editor, my commit message gets the comments appended to it, such as:

```
[TestHook] Test # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit. # On
```

I copied the commit-msg script from an example on the web and altered a bit for my needs.  However, I'm no bash scripting expert so I suspect there is a problem with my script.  Hoping to get some help with it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try and change the commit message **template** (see [`git commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_options)):

> When editing the commit message, start the editor with the contents in the given file.
>   The **`commit.template`** configuration variable is often used to give this option implicitly to the command.

Try a:

```
git config commit.template /path/to/empty/commit/message/template
```

If that template file is empty, your `git commit` shouldn't append anything.

Comment: It's a good workaround, but I'm hoping to figure out why the commit-msg script is causing problems in the first place.  I'll keep this in mind though, thanks!

Comment: @odinsride it should cause problem because it used the default commit message template. Hence my workaround.

Comment: So I have tried this, but the message template still contains those # comments when I issue git commit.  I set the template to ~/.gitmessage.txt, with a single line in the file that says "Something" just to test the functionality.  When I issue git commit, I see: `Something^M

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch TestHook
# Changes to be committed:
#       modified:   test_file_renamed.txt
#`

Answer (score 2):

After lots of Googling, I corrected my script to use grep instead of cat, and it works beautifully now:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Automatically adds branch name to every commit message.
#
BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | awk -F'/' '{print $3}')

if [ -n "$BRANCH" ]; then
        echo ["$BRANCH"'] '$(egrep -v '(^#|^\s*$|^\s*\t*#)' "$1") > "$1"
fi
```

The grep command excludes lines starting with #, or starting with space/tab followed by the # (not totally necessary but threw it in anyway).

Comment: Great catch. The commit message template isn't involved after all, then. +1